Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/*
Today, I met some strange messages about missing Nvidia firmware during the execution of a system upgrade with apt on an Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS ThinkPad P15s laptop.
What are these messages and is there anything I can do to avoid them / fix the problem:
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad107/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad107/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad107/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad107/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad106/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad106/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad106/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad106/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad104/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad104/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad104/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad104/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad103/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad103/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad103/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad103/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad102/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad102/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad102/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ad102/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga107/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga106/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga104/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga103/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga102/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga100/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga100/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga100/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/ga100/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu117/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu117/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu117/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu117/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu116/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu116/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu116/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu116/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu106/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu106/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu106/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu106/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu104/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu104/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu104/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu104/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu102/gsp/gsp-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu102/gsp/bootloader-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu102/gsp/booter_unload-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/tu102/gsp/booter_load-535.113.01.bin for module nouveau
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p5
I: (UUID=3bbbe6fe-a2c0-49b8-9dae-59fc213f963d)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

Here is more information:
$ neofetch --stdout | grep "OS\|Kernel\|CPU\|GPU"
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 2.000GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro T500 Mobile 
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]

# lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:195 memory:6052000000-6052ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: TU117GLM [Quadro T500 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:178 memory:bd000000-bdffffff memory:6040000000-604fffffff memory:6050000000-6051ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)

The linux-firmware package is up-to-date:
# apt-cache policy linux-firmware
linux-firmware:
  Installed: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31
  Candidate: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31
  Version table:
 *** 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.31 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.14 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages

List of current ubuntu drivers:
# ubuntu-drivers list
nvidia-driver-550, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-550-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-545, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545)
nvidia-driver-550-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-550-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-470, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-470-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-470-server-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535-server-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-545-open, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545-open)
nvidia-driver-450-server, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-450-server)

List of current ubuntu drivers' devices:
# ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001FBBsv000017AAsd000022CBbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU117GLM [Quadro T500 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-545-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-545 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550-open - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

I'm wondering which graphical driver should I use then (if that would fix the original issue)?
Here is also a sreenshot from the software-properties-gtk:


Seems like you have some problem with the "nouveau" nvidia driver.
You have two options:

Fix the your current driver "nouveau"

Make this to install firmware files:
sudo apt install linux-firmware
And then this:
sudo update-initramfs -u
To rebuild the initial RAM filesystem.

Purge your current driver and install a more recent one.
Simply make the:
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
or go to additional drivers application and change to other nvidia driver.



From the ubuntu-driver help: autoinstall  Deprecated, please use "install" instead.  Hence which one does autoinstall chose from the list of available drivers? Because I can see 11 different versions (see updates in the main post).

Choose the first one, the nvidia-driver-550 (proprietary, tested)
According to your linux distribution that should be the recomended option for your setup.
